# How can I write a bash script that communicates with other pods while INSIDE a pod?

Tags: bash, kubernetes

I am on a Kubernetes service mesh, and I have lots of scripts that can easily send commands out to (and get responses from) other pods. These scripts are located on the Kubernetes file directory, but not in an actual pod.

To this end, I use 'kubectl exec $namespace-$podA-UID -c $namespace-podA -n $namespace -- /bin/sh -c 'ls'

So the above statement says go to PodA, run the command 'ls', and then show me all the contents of this pod. I have lots of different commands, but that's basically the gist.

Client requests that we have the exact same thing (sample: 'ls' of a pod), but the scripts shouldn't be located in the Kubernetes directory. The bash (.sh) scripts needs to exist on Pod B. So I console (k exec -it ....) into Pod B, navigate to script location, and run it, and it tells me the 'ls' of Pod A. Or Pod C, D, etc... whatever we have in our namespace.

I did some googling and I see the devops teams did in fact create services for each pod. (kubectl get svc -n $namespace).

What is the verbiage to reach out to other pods while you are inside a pod? I try the k exec command above, and I get "/bin/sh: kubectl: not found"

Does kubernetes have to be installed in a dockerfile too? What would be the easiest way to go about this?

thanks!

Comment: First, what are you trying to do? Can you not send a http request to the other pod? It is hard to tell what you ask about.

Comment: In the setup as you're proposing it, the Pod that has the scripts would need to run with a ServiceAccount with appropriate RBAC permissions to be able to run `exec` commands on other Pods, and also to contain the `kubectl` CLI or a similar client library in your application.  It seems unusual to me to need `kubectl exec` so much (or to need it at all, outside of debugging scenarios); can you set this up a different way?

Comment: @DavidMaze We use `kubectl exec` because it allows us to perform actions on pods, especially from our local VM (non-Kubernetes). Logging into our Kubernetes environment is a pain, we have to ssh, enter password, get the current UID of the pod we want to deal with, copy and paste commands. It's far easier to have scripts that automate these initial steps for us. We have scripts to console into pods, delete them, pass arguments into running applications on pods, and even run database queries.

I'm not DevOps, just work with them alot. I will pass your idea along and see what they say. Thanks!!

Comment: You shouldn't have to do any of that, though.  Without a container you'd never get an interactive shell inside, say, a JVM to run administrative commands; that normally wouldn't be part of a containerized setup either.